# Ayuda método en Java

Tags: java

Buenas tardes soy algo nuevo utilizando Java y métodos, estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio que me dejaron en la universidad de una forma mas simplificada, ya lo tengo hecho pero con muchas lineas de código, me pueden ayudar en que estoy fallando por favor, a la hora de digitar 1 es hombre 2 mujer. Cuando imprimo mi método me salen 1 1 1 2 2 (suponiendo que digite 3 veces hombre y 2 veces mujer), como hago si no digite mujer que me salga algo así 1 1 1 0 0.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RestauranteExamen
{ // Inicio primero.

    public static void main(String args[])
    { // Inicio segundo.

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declaracion de variables
        int generoHM [] = new int [5];


        for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i+1) +"Digite: \n1) Masculino \n2) Femenino");
            generoHM [i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    System.out.println("Hombres: ");
    generoSexo(generoHM);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Mujeres: ");
    generoSexo(generoHM);

    } // Fin segundo.


    public static void generoSexo(int generoHM[])
    { // Inicio metodo.

        for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
        { // Inicio for.

            if(generoHM [i] == 1)
            {
                System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
            }
            else if(generoHM [i] == 2)
            {
                System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
            }

        } // Fin for.


    } // Fin metodo.

    }// Fin primero.
```

1. Queremos realizar una encuesta a 10 personas, en esta encuesta indicaremos el sexo (1=masculino, 2=femenino), si trabaja (1=si trabaja, 2= no trabaja) y su sueldo (si tiene un trabajo, sino será un cero) estará entre 600 y 2000 (valor entero). Los valores pueden ser generados aleatoriamente. Calcula y muestra lo siguiente:
   a.  Porcentaje de hombres (tengan o no trabajo).
   b.  Porcentaje de mujeres (tengan o no trabajo).
   c.  Porcentaje de hombres que trabajan.
   d.  Porcentaje de mujeres que trabajan.
   e.  El sueldo promedio de los hombres que trabajan.
   f.  EL sueldo promedio de las mujeres que trabajan.

Comment: creo que faltan algunos casos a la pregunta como por ejemplo. los hombres y mujeres pueden ser digitados al azar, no sabes si va a presionar hombre o mujer, por ende no puedes decir exactamente que no dígito mujer ? o tienen un orden especifico los 3 primeros numero en digital son hombres ? si no digital 1 ni 2 en ese caso es 0 o solamente no es mujer. puede digital cualquier numero ? etc. creo que falta desarrollar un poco la pregunta es muy ambigua. saludos

Comment: Hola @Keylor, ya que se trata de un problema universitario. Podrías dejar escrito tal enunciado para que podamos ayudarle mejor?.

Comment: Correcto puede digitar cualquier valor ya sea 1 o 2.

Answer (score 0):

Tu `for` se está repitiendo 5 veces siempre, entonces debes agregar una forma de representar que no se digitaron hombres y que no se digitaron mujeres, para al final poder distinguir entre estos e imprimirlos en su respectivo lugar, si asuminos que digitar "0" es que no se agregaron mujeres entonces solo agrega este otro for al final de tu método main:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++) {
    if(generoHM[i] == 0)
    System.out.print("0 ");
}
```

Pero esto no es lo más correcto, por que ¿cómo representas que no se agregaron hombres? deberías usar otro simbolo diferente de "0" o mejor aun, usar 2 arreglos diferentes o 2 tipos de objetos diferentes, te puedo ayudar con esto si lo necesitas.

Comment: Hola, yo puedo digitar 1(hombres) , 2 (mujeres), siempre tengo que digitar alguno de esos valores. Pero como hago para que cuando se imprima el array. Suponiendo que digite 2 hombres y 3 mujeres salga algo asi. Hombres 1 , 1 , 0 , 0, 0 | Mujeres 0 , 0 , 2 , 2 , 2. Todo eso respetando los indices del array por decirlo asi.

Answer (score 0):

en caso de que hayas cargado 3 hombres, y luego hayas ingresado otros numeros que no representen al de la mujer, se mostraría con 0.

public static void generoSexo(int generoHM[])
    { // Inicio metodo.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
    { // Inicio for.

        if(generoHM [i] == 1)
        {
            System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
        }
        else if(generoHM [i] == 2)
        {
            System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("0"+" ");
        }

    } // Fin for.


} // Fin metodo.
```

O mejor para tu codigo , por lo visto quieres mostrar a un genero, y luego al otro, sería mejor agregar un atributo mas al metodo especificando el sexo deseado:

public static void generoSexo(int generoHM[], int numeroDeSexo)
    { // Inicio metodo.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
    { // Inicio for.

        if(generoHM [i] == numeroDeSexo)
        {
           System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
        }else{
           System.out.print("0"+" ");//No es del genero especificado=0
        }

    } // Fin for.


} // Fin metodo.
```

Así se vería mejor. Otra recomendación es poner nombres mas descriptivos, al método llamarlo, mostrarSexo, ya con esto pre-sabes que el código te va a mostrar un sexo. En caso contrario, si lees generoSexo, no te da una clara idea de lo que va a tener el método dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres una forma simplificada y estas utilizando Java 1.8 utiliza las funciones `lambdas` y `streams`en lugar de tener un método para imprimir puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RestauranteExamen
{ // Inicio primero.

    public static void main(String args[])
    { // Inicio segundo.

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declaracion de variables
        int generoHM [] = new int [5];


        for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i+1) +"Digite: \n1) Masculino \n2) Femenino");
            generoHM [i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    System.out.println("Hombres: ");
   Arrays.stream(generoHM).forEach(i -> System.out.print( (i ==1?i:0) + " "));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Mujeres: ");
    Arrays.stream(generoHM).forEach(i -> System.out.print( (i ==2?i:0) + " "));;

    } // Fin segundo.

  }// Fin primero.
```

La línea: `Arrays.stream(generoHM).forEach(i -> System.out.print( (i ==2?i:0) + " "));;` indica que el arreglo `generoHM` lo convierta en un flujo de enteros   y que recorra cada uno ellos y ejecute la funcion lambda: `i -> System.out.print( (i ==2?i:0) + " ")` donde `i` es cada carácter del arreglo para imprimir su valor. Con ello va a imprimir 1 o 2 en la posición que fue ingresada y pondrá 0 a las otras.

Answer (score 0):

Un problema que encuentro es la validación de los datos de entrada. Prácticamente puedes ingresar cualquier cosa y el programa lo acepta como una entrada válida. Dado que se trata de una encuesta, los valores nulos afectarían el estudio que estuvieses realizando. Por lo tanto, recomiendo que cuando el usuario ingrese un dato, este sea validado por alguna función y establezcas la acción en consecuencia de datos inválidos. Esta acción puede ser establecer un valor de entrada inválida (por ejemplo -1 o 0) o establecer una condición para que muestre el error e intente de nuevo capturarlo.
    Ahora, en la parte de impresión una posible solución sería que en la función **sexoGenero** agregues otro argumento para especificar que deseas imprimir y utilizarlo en una comparación contra los valores del vector de datos. Algo así:

```
public static void generoSexo(int generoHM[], int sexo){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
    {
        if(generoHM [i] == sexo)
        {
            System.out.print(generoHM[i]+" ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("0 ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hola tomando tu ejemplo

> Suponiendo que digite 2 hombres y 3 mujeres salga algo asi. Hombres 1
>   , 1 , 0 , 0, 0 | Mujeres 0 , 0 , 2 , 2 , 2.

```
public static String[] generoSexo(int generoHM[])
{ // Inicio metodo.

    String hombres = "";
    String mujeres = "";
    Arrays.sort(generoHM);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
    { // Inicio for.
        if(generoHM [i] == 1)
        {
            hombres += "1";
        }else{
            hombres += "0";
        }

        if(generoHM [i] == 2)
        {
            mujeres += "2";
        }else{
            mujeres += "0";
        }

    } // Fin for.

     String[] r = {hombres, mujeres};
     return r;
} // Fin metodo.

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declaracion de variables
    int generoHM [] = new int [5];


    for(int i = 0 ; i < generoHM.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println((i+1) +"Digite: \n1) Masculino \n2) Femenino");
        generoHM [i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    String resultado[] = generoSexo(generoHM);
    System.out.println("Hombres: ");
    System.out.println(resultado[0]);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Mujeres: ");
    System.out.println(resultado[1]);


    }
```

El resultado es

Hombres: 
11000

Mujeres: 
00222